# Is it possible to pass a String variable as argument to new ImageIcon()?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

Im adding a jlabel with an image to a jpanel. If I hard code the image url then it works fine but I want an array of URLs so I wanted to know if the command jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(????)) could be passed a String variable?

```
private JPanel right;
private JLabel jl= new JLabel();

right = new JPanel();
right.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,10,10));
this.add(right, BorderLayout.CENTER);

jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ships[0]));
right.add(jl);
validate();
```

Comment: what's `ships[0]`? If it's a string, looks fine to me.

Comment: reading documentation might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: ships is an array of Strings. so ships[0] is the first string in the array.Does that still look right?

Answer (score 1):

According the the docs it should accept a path to the file, assuming `ships[0]` is a String.

```
 public ImageIcon(String filename)
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29)